# Adding variables together from 1 post request (python)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have some code, it works as expected, but im having a difficult time trying to add my global_criticalvulnerabilities to a master variable, that adds up ALL post request responses

```
from logging import critical
from unittest import result
import requests, json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Basic auth=='
        }
payload = {
    "match" : "all",
    "filters" : [
        {"field": "site-id",
        "operator": "in",
        "values": [
            "22"]},
        {"field": "owner-tag",
        "operator": "contains",
        "value":"DESKTOP_SUPPORT"},
        {"field": "operating-system",
        "operator": "contains",
        "value":"microsoft"},
        {"field": "vulnerability-category",
        "operator": "does-not-contain",
        "value":"microsoft_patch"},]}

global_CritiicalVulnerabilities1 = ""
global_CritiicalVulnerabilities = ""
global_SevereVulnerabilities = ""
global_ModerateVulnerabilities = ""

if global_CritiicalVulnerabilities == 0: #if nothing then continuely add up each criticalvuln from each post request/response

    for page in range(1,249):

        url1 = 'https://url:3780/api/3/assets/search?size=2&page=%s'%page
        print(url1)
        response = requests.post(url1, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=False)
        json_response = response.json()

        vulnerabilities = []
        resources = json_response['resources']
        for d in resources:
            if 'vulnerabilities' in d:
                vulnerabilities.append(d['vulnerabilities'])
        criticalVuln = sum(x.get('critical', 0) for x in vulnerabilities)
        print(vulnerabilities)
        criticalVuln = str(criticalVuln)

    global_CritiicalVulnerabilities1 = criticalVuln + criticalVuln
    print(global_CritiicalVulnerabilities)
    print("The grand total Critical Vuln: " + global_CritiicalVulnerabilities)
    #print("The grand total Severe Vuln: " + totalSevere)
    #print("The grand total Moderate Vuln: " + totalModerate)
```

Could someone help guide me in the direction i should go? I dont really want the answer right away, trying to learn and understand how i should be thinking like a computer...

im trying to add up criticalVuln to itself so it has the grand total of every critical Vulnerability

i tried this as well, and its not doing what i want it to do

Comment: "i tried this as well, and its not doing what i want it to do" What **do** you want it to do? What does it mean to "add" post request responses? When you try this code, does `vulnerabilities` contain what it should? If it does - then a) give an example of what is in that list; b) explain **exactly what should be returned** for that input. Please read [mre] and focus the code on the part that **actually causes the problem**. If the request handling code gets the correct data, but the processing is wrong, then **only** show processing code that is self-contained and is given hard-coded input.

Comment: You assign an empty string to global_CritiicalVulnerabilities then test it for equality with zero.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code.